# Are printers' drivers specific to the motherboard CPU brand?

Tags: drivers, printer

I noticed in my Windows XP's Print Server Properties box, under the Drivers tab, that my 1994 (year) inkjet printer's driver lists under Environment: "Intel".  Are printers' drivers specific to the motherboard CPU brand?  I can't install this driver on a newer (Windows 7) AMD-based machine and I'm wondering if that's why.

Edit: Added image:

[image]

Comment: The "_motherboard_" and "_CPU_" are typically separate components within a system. The term "_Intel_" is often used to refer to "_x86_", which also commonly refers to "_x86_64_" (i.e: 64-bit PCs)... I don't know what this "_Environment_" column is referring to, but it's certainly nothing to do with the CPU manufacturer (i.e: Intel / AMD / VIA / etc...). Printers aren't tied to a particular motherboard or subset of motherboards, though they may require exotic (by today's standards) interfaces, like a real parallel port - USB adapters often don't cut it.

Comment: Note also that the driver model for Windows XP vs. Windows 7 is very different - so you cannot use a Windows XP driver to operate the printer from a Windows 7 system... devices like printers often do not get driver updates for newer operating systems, and either become reliant on older systems to keep working (a significant consideration including management resources, security, power, etc...), or are destined to be replaced.

Comment: @Attie Printers aren't tied to the CPU brand, but is it possible their drivers are, or do AMD CPUs run the same (Intel) code natively without conversion?  I've studied the Windows GDI-to-spooler mechanisms and realize they are different on XP versus 7, but I haven't found much helpful that describes printer driver design.

Comment: This seems to explain the reason for the Environment setting: [link](https://www.utilizewindows.com/print-management-in-xp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is, No. Printers are in no way geared to a specific computer motherboard. Modern printers will work with any computer and operating system for which the printer has a driver.

If your printer is XP era, it may (easily) not have a modern driver.

Try Windows Devices and Printers, Add a Printer to see if you can find the printer. If not, it is likely too old.

To check printer installation, go to Devices and Printer and click on Add Printer.  Try the printer or something very close to the printer model you have.

Comment: So why do you think Windows XP would go out of its way to mention "Environment"?

Comment: Printer manufacturers generally do not update their own drivers for very old printers. This is normal. Windows has taken on this chore by providing generic drivers for old printers. You can (as noted in my answer) use Windows Devices and Printers for an appropriate driver if it exists.  Your question was "is the printer tied to a specific motherboard?" and the answer remains, No.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I looked, and no appropriate driver exists in Windows 7, so I was trying to understand the print driver system in Windows in general.  As an embedded device driver developer, I don't get why they would bother mentioning 'Environment: Intel' if it was irrelevant.

Comment: "Environment" includes hardware and operating system and is not just hardware. XP is so old that even the way things were said back then change. If there is no generic driver, then the printer is too old. What XP wrote 15 or so years ago no longer applies.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the dialog box I mentioned in the original post.  I don't know if Intel would have been mentioned here if it wasn't important.  (It's the OEM's driver I'm trying to install; Vista/7 shows none.)

Comment: What you show says "no drivers" for the newer OS. Why are you trying to tie your printer to hardware. That is not how they work. You must get a driver (Windows or Manufacturer) for the operating system you have. It appears there is not such a driver.

Comment: This seems to explain the reason for the Environment setting: [link](https://www.utilizewindows.com/print-management-in-xp/).

Comment: That does help a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Then again, why does that link show a DEC Alpha processor in the list of Environments?  Hmm...

Comment: Hard to say, but also, the way XP did things is long in the past.